# Why am I not able to insert values into my child table through my PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I simply want to register users to my site (*which I did successfully*) and once they login, they can donate clothes. I have two tables-

---

**Users-**

- id (int) PRIMARY KEY and AUTO INCREMENT.
- Name (varchar)
- E-mail (varchar)
- Password (varchar)

---

**Clothes-**

- id (int) PRIMARY KEY and AUTO INCREMENT.
- user_id (int) FOREIGN KEY
- Decription (varchar)
- Image (varchar)

---

What I want is that, when the user logs in and clicks on the donate button, it will take the user to this page-

## Fill The Clothes Details

```
    <form action="clothes.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table align="center" width="760px" border="2">

            <td>Clothes Details</td>
            <td><textarea cols="60" rows="10" name="description" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Image</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="register" value="Submit" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

When the user enters the description and uploads the image, I want it to be stored in my PhpMyAdmin table, but with the respective `id` of the user. Here is my PHP script-

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("includes/db.php");
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "clothes/$image");
    $insert = "insert into clothes (description, image) values ( '$description', '$image')";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
    if ($run) {
        echo "<script>alert('Clothes Successfully Donated')</script>";
    }
}

?>
```

And as obvious it may seem, the data is not inserted into the table. When I `echo` the `insert` query, I am getting the query `insert into clothes (user_id, description, image) values ( 'Jeans', 'HUMBLE. - Single.jpg')`, which means my query is working. But I just cannot figure out what the problem is as this is my first experience with foreign keys. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Column count is not equal to values count in insert query!!

Comment: Namely in `insert into clothes (user_id, description, image) values ( '$description', '$image')` the value for user_id is missing.

Comment: @Saty even if I remove 'user_id' or add 'id' in the insert query, it is still not working.

Comment: `user_id` is the required foreign key. You need to find a way to get the corresponding id, e.g. stored in a PHP session.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone and that is what I am asking. How is it done?

Comment: When a user logged in, you could start a [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) holding the id. See also [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). First try to insert a fixed user ID, when it works, start writing code for sessions.

Comment: I see, there actually is already a start_session() in your code. So everything you have to do is `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $id` when you fetched the row from `users` in some place at login time. Then you just insert `$_SESSION['user_id']` as value in your insert statement. Be aware that your approach is highly vulnerable to SQL injections. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone problem solved! Thank you so much. You are a legend!

Comment: Again, I strictly recommend using prepared statements, or anyone can manipulate your queries by simply sending POST data. Imagine what happens, if someone sends a description like `Tom's cat`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to correct the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("includes/db.php");
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "clothes/$image");
    $insert = "insert into clothes (user_id, description, image) values ( $user_id, '$description', '$image')";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
    if ($run) {
        echo "<script>alert('Clothes Successfully Donated')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

First you need to verify, whether you have set the logged in user's id in session, If not then set first then this code will work fine. If you have not set then please set $_SESSION['user_id']=[id of loggedin user].

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How do I fetch the logged-in user's id?

Comment: In this code the user ID is read by `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];`, provided that you have previously stored it into the session at login time.